# Mex files and memory management

Tags: matlab, memory, mex

I have a mex code where the output variable has the same name as the input variable, but it changes size as a result of the operations of the mex code. For instance, I have something like:

A=Function(A) where A in the input is a 100 X 1 vector (much much larger in my simulation) and the output A is a 50 X 1 vector. I want to understand how memory is managed in this situation. After the operation is finished, does A now occupy 50 X 1 worth of space and the rest is free to allocate to other variables?

Thanks!

Siddharth

Comment: Very interesting question.  I had thought I knew the answer, but in the process of answering the question, I actually learned some interesting and unexpected things about how this is handled.

Comment: Also have a look at my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19850676/2778484) where I looked at the shared copy mechanism.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is correct, the data buffer for the original `A` is destroyed by MATLAB and a new buffer is created (the same `mxArray` structure address is reused presumably by copying the new one onto the original after deallocating the original array's data buffer).  **This is assuming you are *not* writing to `prhs[i]` in you MEX file!**

You can see this with `format debug`.  You will observed that the output `mxArray` has the same address, but it's data buffer has a different address, so it has clearly reallocated the output array.  This suggests that the original buffer is deallocated or queued to be deallocated.

Starting with the output for a change, of the file `testMEX.mexw64` that takes the first half of the input array's first row and copies it into a new array:

```
>> format debug
>> A = rand(1,8)
A =

Structure address = efbb890
m = 1
n = 8
pr = 77bb6c40
pi = 0
    0.2581    0.4087    0.5949    0.2622    0.6028    0.7112    0.2217    0.1174
>> A = testMEX(A)
A =

Structure address = efbb890
m = 1
n = 4
pr = 77c80380
pi = 0
    0.2581    0.4087    0.5949    0.2622
```

Note that `pr` is **different**, meaning that MATLAB has created a new data buffer.  However, the `mxArray` "Structure address" is the same.  So, at the minimum, the old data buffer will be deallocated.  Whether or not the original `mxArray` structure is simply mutated or a new `mxArray` is created is another question (see below).

---

**Edit:** The following is some evidence to suggest that an entirely new `mxArray` is created and it is copied onto the old `mxArray`

Add the following two lines to the MEX function:

```
mexPrintf("prhs[0] = %X, mxGetPr = %X, value = %lf\n", 
    prhs[0], mxGetPr(prhs[0]), *mxGetPr(prhs[0]));
mexPrintf("plhs[0] = %X, mxGetPr = %X, value = %lf\n", 
    plhs[0], mxGetPr(plhs[0]), *mxGetPr(plhs[0]));
```

The result is:

```
prhs[0] = EFBB890, mxGetPr = 6546D840, value = 0.258065
plhs[0] = EFA2DA0, mxGetPr = 77B65660, value = 0.258065
```

Clearly there is **a temporary `mxArray`** at EFA2DA0 containing the output (`plhs[0]`), and this `mxArray` header/structure is entirely copied onto the old `mxArray` structure (the one as `A` in the base MATLAB workspace).  Before this copy happens, MATLAB surely deallocates the data buffer at `6546D840`.

**testMEX.cpp**

```
#include "mex.h"

void mexFunction(int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[],  int nrhs, const mxArray *prhs[])
{
    mxAssert(nrhs == 1 && mxGetM(prhs[0]) == 1, "Input must be a row vector.");
    double *A = mxGetPr(prhs[0]);
    size_t cols = mxGetN(prhs[0]);
    size_t newCols = cols / 2;

    plhs[0] = mxCreateDoubleMatrix(1, newCols, mxREAL);

    for (int i = 0; i < newCols; ++i)
        mxGetPr(plhs[0])[i] = A[i];

    mexPrintf("prhs[0] = %X, mxGetPr = %X, value = %lf\n", 
        prhs[0], mxGetPr(prhs[0]), *mxGetPr(prhs[0]));
    mexPrintf("plhs[0] = %X, mxGetPr = %X, value = %lf\n", 
        plhs[0], mxGetPr(plhs[0]), *mxGetPr(plhs[0]));

}
```