# Store std::strings in mex cell array

Tags: matlab, mex

Inspired from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18847833/is-it-possible-return-cell-array-that-contains-one-instance-in-several-cells), I am interested to pass `std::strings` into the cell array. However, the `mxDuplicateArray` accepts `mxArray` format variables. I have tried to transform the `std::string` to `mxArray` with `mxGetString` but without success.

Could you please make a suggestion on this?

Thanks!

```
void mexFunction(int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[],int nrhs, const mxArray *prhs[])
{
    std::string str ("Hellooo"); 
    const char *cstr = str.c_str();
    mwSize len = 10;
    mxArray *mxarr = mxCreateCellMatrix(len, 1);
    mxArray *mxstr = mxCreateString("");
    mxGetString(mxstr, (char*) cstr, str.length());
    for(mwIndex i=0; i<len; i++) {
        // I simply replaced the call to mxDuplicateArray here
        mxSetCell(mxarr, i, mxDuplicateArray(mxstr));
    }
    mxDestroyArray(mxstr);
    plhs[0] = mxarr;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also cut out the call to `mxDuplicateArray` (and `mxDestroyArray`).

```
#include "mex.h"
#include <string>
void mexFunction(int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[], int nrhs, const mxArray *prhs[])
{
    std::string str("Hellooo"); 
    const char *cstr = str.c_str();
    mwSize len = 10;
    mxArray *mxarr = mxCreateCellMatrix(len, 1);
    for (mwIndex i=0; i<len; i++) {
        mxSetCell(mxarr, i, mxCreateString(cstr));
    }
    plhs[0] = mxarr;
}
```

Untested...

Comment: @Thoth I think the MATLAB memory manager owns each string, but now that I look at the docs, ti says to use `mxDestroyArray`...

Comment: @chappjc: actually your code is correct as is; cell-arrays (and structure fields) are supposed to "steal" ownership of pointers, so you shouldn't free an array assigned to a cell

Comment: @Amro Not suggesting to free the array assigned to the cell, just to ensure that MATLAB knows to free the `mxArray` when the cell is cleared (does the `mxArray` captured by the cell get handles by MATLAB garbage collection). Kind of like `mxFastZeros` creates an array that requries `mxCreateSharedDataCopy` to get a "managed" array. If needed (not sure), the way to do that is with `mxDuplicateArray` or maybe `mxCreateReference`.

Comment: Just tested with enormous number and size of strings and it seems to release memory when the cell is cleared, so I guess it's OK.

Comment: yes, cell and struct arrays are destroyed recursively, including the member cells and fields: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/memory-management-issues.html#brfpzpx-1, hence no memory is leaked in the example above

Comment: @Amro Right, upon `clear` you can even watch the memory usage go down in the task manager as it cycles through each cell.  It makes sense that when the cell gets each array, MATLAB will ensure each one is cleared when the cell itself cleared.  I was a little uncertain since you can't just let the output of `mxCreateString` go undestroyed in a MEX file, but actually when the string joins a cell array it crosses into the managed MATLAB workspace.  Nice exercise.

Answer (score 1):

From the docs on `mxGetString`:

> Call mxGetString to copy the character data of a string mxArray

What you want, is the opposite: create an `mxArray` from a c-style string. For that you can use
`mxCreateString` directly. It seems to tried to use it to create an empty string at first. This should work:

```
void mexFunction(int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[],int nrhs, const mxArray *prhs[])
{
    std::string str ("Hellooo"); 
    const char *cstr = str.c_str();
    mwSize len = 10;
    mxArray *mxarr = mxCreateCellMatrix(len, 1);
    mxArray *mxstr = mxCreateString(cstr);
    // no need for this line
    // mxGetString(mxstr, (char*) cstr, str.length());
    for(mwIndex i=0; i<len; i++) {
        // I simply replaced the call to mxDuplicateArray here
        mxSetCell(mxarr, i, mxDuplicateArray(mxstr));
    }
    mxDestroyArray(mxstr);
    plhs[0] = mxarr;
}
```

Comment: That was under my nose:)Thanks!!